# Assigning complex values to character elements of data frame in R

Tags: r

There are three columns in my data frame which are characters, "A","B", and "C" (this order can vary for different data frames). I want to assign values to them, A= 1+0i, B=2+3i and C=3+2i. I use as.complex(factor(col1)) and the same thing for column two and three, but it makes all three column equal to 1+0i!!

```
col1 <- c("A","A", "A")
col2 <- c("B", "B","B")
col3 <- c("C","C","C")
df <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
print(df)
A= 1+0i
B=2+3i
C=3+2i
df2<- transform(df, col1=as.complex(as.factor(col1)),col2=as.complex(as.factor(col2)),col3=as.complex(as.factor(col3)))
sapply(df2,class)
View(df2)
```

Comment: Please share input data reproducibly. And why are you starting with `as.factor()`? Not sure why you're using `as.factor()` at all...

Comment: I'll edit it right now. Someone suggested to use factor().

Comment: If I don't use factor, it will make those three columns NA.

Comment: I also used: ``` newlevels <- c(A=1+0i,B=2+3i,C=3+2i)
relevel(df,newlevels) but there is an error:  Error in relevel.default(df, newlevels) : 
  'relevel' only for (unordered) factors

Comment: Now that we can see your input it makes more sense why you might try `factor`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can fixe the problem?

Answer (score 2):

So this is a weird thing you're doing. You have a column of strings, letters like `"A"` and `"B"`. Then you have objects with the same names, `A = 1 + 0i`, etc. Normally we don't treat object names as "data", but you're sort of mixing the two here. The solution I'd propose is to make everything data: combine your `A`, `B`, and `C` values into a vector, and give the vector names accordingly. Then we can replace the values in the data frame with the corresponding values from our named vector:

```
vec = c(A, B, C)
names(vec) = c("A", "B", "C")
df[] = lapply(df, \(x) vec[x])
df
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1 1+0i 2+3i 3+2i
# 2 1+0i 2+3i 3+2i
# 3 1+0i 2+3i 3+2i
```

Comment: Thank you so much, in the data frame I receive they are saved as character, but they are complex number and  are equal to a specific value, the order of them changes, like ABC, ACB from data frame to data frame. what does \(x) vec[x] mean?

Comment: In r-4.2.0 `\(x)` is a shortcut for `function(x)` as seen above in anonymous function on vec.

Comment: Would you please also explain what does df[] = lapply(df, \(x) vec[x]) do?

Comment: `lapply` applies a function to every column of a data frame. `df[] =` assigns the result back to the data frame---normally `lapply` returns a `list`, but the `[]` makes sure we assign it to the existing data frame structure`. We call the argument of our function `x`, so `x` will be equal to each of the columns of the data frame in turn. `vec[x]` subsets our vector `vec` by `x`, the values of the current data frame column, and that is the result of the function.

Comment: If you try it out on a data frame where the order changes, you should see that it still works just fine. I just used the sample data from your question.

Comment: I had to redo the column ordering, col1 <- c('A' ... col2 <- c('C'... to df2 <- data.frame(col1, col3 ...  steps to address the ABC, ACB, BCA mapping changes mentioned(and vec order), and after dfBCA[] <- lapply(df, \(x) vec[x]) works fine, otherwise I was getting invalid type errors (language, complex) on vec[x].